# An item name lenght should be less or equal to 100 while installing a content package

Tags: installation

I've got a vanilla instance of Sitecore 8.2 installed on my sandbox and I'm getting this error (taken from the logs):

> Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.InvalidItemNameException Message: An
>   item name lenght should be less or equal to 100. Source:
>   Sitecore.Kernel    at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemUtil.AssertItemName(Item
>   destinationItem, String name)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.set_Name(String value)    at
>   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item
>   version)    at
>   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode
>   versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode, IProcessingContext
>   context, Boolean removeOtherVersions)    at
>   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry)

What config setting do I need to change in order to get past this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct way to resolve this would be to fix the cause of the issue and reduce the item length to less than 100 on the problematic item.

As you have also found, you can increase the `MaxItemNameLength` to a higher number to get around the issue.

Be aware though, the `Name` field in the `Items` table in the database has a data type of `nvarchar(256)` so setting this value to more than 256 may cause you issues.

I would also recommend you revert this setting back to 100 (by deleting your patch config) after installing your content package since this directly affects your URLs and your content editors may therefore be able to create very long item names. Again, I highly recommend you identify the problematic item and reduce the item length to not cause issues in the future.

Comment: Those are good things to note. Especially understanding that the table only holds 256 characters.

Answer (score 6):

In Sitecore.config file, you need to find this item:

```
<!--  MAX ITEM NAME
        Specifies the maximum length of an item name.
        Default value: 100
  -->
<setting name="MaxItemNameLength" value="100" />
```

Change the value here to be something bigger, maybe like "1000".

I would do this in a patch file, though, and not directly in the sitecore.config file, as doing this in a patch file makes upgrading in the future much easier.